# Drawer /Slider Layout for windows phone on Xamarin.Forms (portable)?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

Is it possible to create drawer layout for windows phone as per in the link [Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-81-Now-its-b63049f9) i also reused this C#,Xaml codes on enviroment Xamarin.forms(portable) -VS2015 using DrawerLayout.dll.

I search lot of pages,there is no such clear drawer i found for windows phone in Cross platform.. I try  `MasterdetailPage` program types etc.. Can anyone explain me to make its possible or post me combinations Xamarin layouts to achieve this

And Also may i know whether we can change pages,Layouts depends on paltform(custom platform-specific renderers)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I've self implemented one for iOS. I see no reason why that wouldnt work for WP

Comment: @Dbl ty for your comment,yes the one i need for wp

Comment: what you are trying to do is done with CustomRenderers. You can find out how to do what you want here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WP8

Comment: @Dbl its platform specified right, analysis on it ..just i google n seen custom renderers are for ui designs not for layouts ty

Comment: yeah. you develop the hood of your control in your pcl library and implement the renderers per platform. CustomRenderers are advertised for ui modification, however it's also how the layouts are built too. in that github directory you can also see "BoxViewRenderer", which too - is a layout. It takes some time understanding how to do things, but with source code it is easy enough. The only difficulty is the per platform implementation. With source code it is very doable though.